# EF Core .net 6 connected Entity to View. Login failed for user 'xxxdbtest'

Tags: sql, authentication

I've searched through similar problems but haven't found one that fits my problem.
This is a VS Core .Net 6 Entity Framework project.
Have created the following in my DbContext

```
         public DbSet<ViewRequest> DispatchedQuery { get; set; }

         protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
         {
             //DispatchedCars
             modelBuilder.Entity<ViewRequest>(x =>
                 {
                     x.ToView("Get_DispatchedCars", schema: "dbo");
                     x.HasNoKey();

                 });
         }
```

Everything works perfectly locally, but when I deploy to test server. I get user xxxdbtest unable to login to SQL server. This then applies only to this new code part of executing a view.

[image]

I have tried most of the settings on the SQL server but they all give the same result.
What is missing in the SQL Test server that I have locally. I have looked at all settings and logins locally compared to test SQL server, but can't find any difference.
Has anyone experienced similar?

Comment: there mus an excat erroro message, which will tell more about the error. else give the user all privileges and remove them one by one

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I can't get the log file because the IT department is on vacation right now.
Is there another way to view logs in SQL server? I have access to the server!

Comment: ef core must deliver a comprehensive error message, so add some error handling to your code

Comment: I found the following in Event viewer Application logs
Login failed for user 'xxxdbtest'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
Just like you say I will try to add throw exception in my code to catch error in console. All this just because my real application log is not accessible :)

Comment: that is promising, maybe a typo when the account was added., so change the password of the user to that you  have in your app

Comment: Really what a breakthrough, but it doesn't solve my problem. The IT department has a key value in Jenkins that is used to exchange specific keys depending on which environment you deploy to. They are still on vacation!

Thanks for your input and ideas. Now we're taking a long vacation instead! ;)